# Cannot open a simulink project, showing that the project is empty

Tags: project, simulink

Other colleague can open the project without problems. But on my pc it shows that the project is empty.

I tried to turn of the pc and start again.
I was expecting I can open the project.

I can open the similar project before, but this one is from a colleague. He made some changes and sent to me.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason: the Matlab path is too long! When I moved the folder to a shorter path, I can open the project as expected.